# removing the y-axis margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to make a masonry type layout so I gave random height and colors to the divs but there seem to be a y-axis margin with the divs. I want the divs to have a uniform margin so that they look more like a masonry layout. where am I going wrong with this code?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
const colors = ["palevioletred", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"];

const getRandomItem = items => {
  return items[getUniqueFromRange(0, items.length)];
};

const getUniqueFromRange = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
        {Array.from({ length: 30 }).map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            style={{
              background: getRandomItem(colors),
              height: getUniqueFromRange(100, 200)
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  font: 2em Sansita, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 1 230px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-meitner-h825q?file=/src/styles.scss:0-344)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use a flex-direction of `row`, but you'll have to use a flex direction of `column`: https://w3bits.com/flexbox-masonry/

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to stick with the default flex-direction of `row`, so you'll need to use `flex-direction: column` somewhere. Checkout the codesandbox I've provided in my answer. Alex Haszard seems to have a similar approach as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  font: 2em Sansita, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper > * {
  border: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Try this and see if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a vertical flexbox masonry grid that you're looking for, you will need to have a `flex-direction: column`.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-flex-masonry-jlxsm)

In the above sandbox, I used an arbitrary height of 2000px for the wrapping container, but [this article](https://w3bits.com/flexbox-masonry/) explains a more elegant solution where you calculate the best height of the container using JavaScript which would prevent any excess white-space from showing up in your masonry grid.